# Значення слова "запалений" у рядку "боляче – запалені сильно / органи місцевого самоврядування" у пiснi гурту "Діти інженерів"

Tags: значення-слів

У пісні "[Органи місцевого самоврядування](https://youtu.be/rw49yv9ACfs)" гурту "Діти інженерів" не можу зрозуміти цей рядок:

> [Приспів]
> Кожні день і ніч ломить спину
> Очі червоніють від розчарування
> Боляче – **запалені** сильно
> Органи місцевого самоврядування

Дивився у [словнику](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), але знайшов лише значення, пов'язане з горінням. Можливо, тут сленг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Можливо, тут сленг?

Нї, хоча са́ме слово обігране з [*орґаном*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD_(%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%8F)). Згаданий вами словник наводить потрїбний термін:

> 6. *мед*. Викликати [запалення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) якого-небудь органу або частини тіла. *Корені і плоди [переступня] отруйні.. Вони дуже збуджують і запалюють слизові оболонки шлунка* (Наука. , 1, 1959, 41).